# How can I identify which planet I'm in ? Using only sensors

Tags: physics, signal-processing, mathematical-astronomy

I'm working on a personal project where I want to identify on which planet I'm in using the following sensors:

Accelerometer, Gyroscope, Pedometer, Magnetometer and an Altitude Sensor.

My first idea was to use the Accelerometer to calculate the gravitational force and then identify in which planet I'm in. However, I don't know if this solution will work in different environments, such as mountains or under accelerations provided by a vehicle.

How I can pull this off? Anyone have a better idea ?

Comment: How will the altitude sensor work?  The common ones here use air pressure or GPS data.  Both of those will probably give you a good clue as to where you are.

Comment: The altitude sensor uses a barometer. However, GPS is not available in other planets

Comment: The barometer will need a lot of data to be calibrated.  That data alone would probably tell you where you were.  If you just mean planets within our solar system then the accelerometer is probably enough.  It should be able to tell you the rotational speed and this will tell you where you are.  The gyroscope may also be enough, I guess that it will work like Foucault's Pendulum.

Comment: Very interesting! Where are the sensors located? On a ground vehicle? a satellite?